# Can anyone explain this implementation of depth first search?

Tags: python, algorithm, depth-first-search

So i am learning about search algorithms at the minute, and would appreciate it if someone could provide an explanation of how this implementation of **depth first search** works, i do understand how depth first search works as a algorithm, but i am struggling to grasp how it has been implemented here.

Thanks for your patience and understanding, Below is the code:

```
map = {(0, 0): [(1, 0), (0, 1)],
   (0, 1): [(1, 1), (0, 2)],
   (0, 2): [(1, 2), (0, 3)],
   (0, 3): [(1, 3), (0, 4)],
   (0, 4): [(1, 4), (0, 5)],
   (0, 5): [(1, 5)],
   (1, 0): [(2, 0), (1, 1)],
   (1, 1): [(2, 1), (1, 2)],
   (1, 2): [(2, 2), (1, 3)],
   (1, 3): [(2, 3), (1, 4)],
   (1, 4): [(2, 4), (1, 5)],
   (1, 5): [(2, 5)],
   (2, 0): [(3, 0), (2, 1)],
   (2, 1): [(3, 1), (2, 2)],
   (2, 2): [(3, 2), (2, 3)],
   (2, 3): [(3, 3), (2, 4)],
   (2, 4): [(3, 4), (2, 5)],
   (2, 5): [(3, 5)],
   (3, 0): [(4, 0), (3, 1)],
   (3, 1): [(4, 1), (3, 2)],
   (3, 2): [(4, 2), (3, 3)],
   (3, 3): [(4, 3), (3, 4)],
   (3, 4): [(4, 4), (3, 5)],
   (3, 5): [(4, 5)],
   (4, 0): [(5, 0), (4, 1)],
   (4, 1): [(5, 1), (4, 2)],
   (4, 2): [(5, 2), (4, 3)],
   (4, 3): [(5, 3), (4, 4)],
   (4, 4): [(5, 4), (4, 5)],
   (4, 5): [(5, 5)],
   (5, 0): [(5, 1)],
   (5, 1): [(5, 2)],
   (5, 2): [(5, 3)],
   (5, 3): [(5, 4)],
   (5, 4): [(5, 5)],
   (5, 5): []}

visited = []
path = []
routes = []


def goal_test(node):
    if node == (5, 5):
        return True
    else:
        return False


found = False


def dfs(visited, graph, node):
    global routes
    visited = visited + [node]
    if goal_test(node):
        routes = routes + [visited]
    else:
        for neighbour in graph[node]:
            dfs(visited, graph, neighbour)


dfs(visited, map, (0, 0))
print(len(routes))
for route in routes:
    print(route)
```

Comment: try to visualize it, and create a tree diagram, that will help

Comment: Well, it's not very good, if it starts by shadowing `map`. Then it proceeds to mix an explicit `global` (`routes`) with a passed global (`visited`). In the end, it finds all routes, because it never returns - it works because it's not cyclical (it doesn't check visited to avoid looping)

Comment: I am just confused about how "visited" is allowing DFS to continue it's search without repeating i guess? Unfortunately if i understood what i am not getting then i would try and look it up, apologies for the vagueness, i am just looking for an explanation in steps.

Comment: The more I look at it, the worse it becomes. I think you should forget this implementation. It is not good. This may even run infinitely in circles for other graphs (until stack overflow occurs).

Comment: Okay thanks Grismar this is more what i was looking for, as i get that it is calling itself recursively, but not calling visited

Comment: Oh dear well this is the code that my university has given me as a sample answer to a DFS implementation so this is disappointing to hear

Comment: Are you looking for an improvement?

Comment: Of course trincot i would love to see one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This implementation employs several bad practices:

- `map` is a native Python function, so it is a bad idea to create a variable with that name.
- `visited` should not need to be initialised in the global scope: the caller has no interest in this as it only plays a role in the DFS algorithm itself
- `routes` should not have to be initialised to an empty list either, and it is bad that `dfs` mutates this global variable. Instead `dfs` should *return* that information to the caller. This makes one `dfs` call self-contained, as it returns the possible routes from the *current* node to the target. It is up to the caller to extend the routes in this returned collection with an additional node.
- The body of `goal_test` should be written as `return node == (5, 5)`. The `if ... else` is just translating a boolean value to the same boolean value.
- The function `goal_test` seems overkill when you can just pass an argument to the `dfs` function that represents the target node. This makes it also more generic, as you don't need to hard-code the target location inside a function.
- `path` and `found` are initialised but never used.
- `dfs` would run into a stack overflow if the graph would have cycles. It does not happen with the given graph, because that graph is acyclic, but it would be better if you could also rely on this function when giving it cyclic graphs.
- `dfs` will visit the same cell multiple times, as it can be found via different paths (like for instance `(2,2)`), and so from there it will perform the same DFS search it already did before. This could be made slightly more efficient by storing the result it got from a previous visit to that cell, i.e. we could use memoization. The gain is small, as most time is spent on creating and copying paths. The gain (of using memoization) would be significant if the function would only *count* the number of paths, and not build them.

Here is an implementation that deals with the above mentioned points. It uses a wrapper function to hide the use of memoization to the caller, and to reduce the number of arguments that need to be passed to `dfs`:

```
def search(graph, source, target):
    # Use memoization to avoid repetitive DFS from same node, 
    #  Also used to mark a node as visited, to avoid runnning in cycles
    memo = dict()  # has routes that were already collected

    def dfs(node):
        if node not in memo:  # not been here before
            if node == target:
                memo[node] = [[target]]
            else:
                # Mark with None that this node is on the current path
                #   ...avoiding infinite recursion on a cycle
                memo[node] = None  # temporary value while not yet back from recursion
                memo[node] = [
                    [node] + route 
                        for neighbour in graph[node]
                            for route in dfs(neighbour) 
                                if route
                ]
        return memo[node]

    return dfs(source)

graph = {(0, 0): [(1, 0), (0, 1)],
    # ...etc ... 
}

routes = search(graph, (0, 0), (5, 5))

print(len(routes))
for route in routes:
    print(route)
```